# grails, mongodb gorm, null embedded objects

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

I have this two simple domain classes:

```
class Isa95EquipmentSpecification {

    String equipmentClass
    String equipment
    String description
    Float quantity
    String quantityUOM
    List<Isa95EquipmentSpecificationProperty> equipmentSpecificationProperties

    static embedded = ['equipmentSpecificationProperties']

    static constraints = {
        equipment nullable: true, validator: {val, obj -> if (null == val && null ==    obj.equipmentClass) return ['bothNullable']}
        equipmentClass nullable: true, validator: {val, obj -> if (null == val && null == obj.equipment) return ['bothNullable']}
        description nullable: true
        quantity nullable: true
        quantityUOM nullable: true  
    }
}
```

and the child domain:

```
class Isa95EquipmentSpecificationProperty {
    String name
    String description
    String value
    String valueUOM
    Double quantity
    String quantityUOM

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false
        description nullable: true
        value nullable: false
        valueUOM nullable: false
        quantity nullable: true
        quantityUOM nullable: true
    }
}
```

I expect that building up a composed document whit embedded properties I can save it running just a save() operation on the parent but it doesn't work.

I try to run on the grails console:

```
    def prop1 = new isa95.productdefinition.Isa95EquipmentSpecificationProperty(name: 'prop-1', value: 'mad', valueUOM: '-')
def prop2 = new isa95.productdefinition.Isa95EquipmentSpecificationProperty(name: 'prop-2', value: 12.32, valueUOM: 'kilograms')
def spec = new isa95.productdefinition.Isa95EquipmentSpecification(equipment: '41500', description: 'eq-test', equipmentSpecificationProperties: [prop1, prop2])
spec.save(failOnError: true)
```

The script run correctly but in the db I found this. I expected to find equipmentSpecificationProperies populated with nested list:

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong(9), "description" : "eq-test", "equipment" : "14500", "equipmentSpecificationProperties" : [ null, null ], "version" : 0 }
```

Comment: I'd remove `hasMany` from your `Isa95EquipmentSpecification` class

Comment: @injecteer I removed `hasMany` but got the some result

Comment: `"equipmentSpecificationProperties" : [ null, null ]` this makes me think, that the objects are being persisted as sub-docs. you should be able to see the equipmentSpecificationProperties array with some elements in a mongo-browser

Comment: If I call `spec.save()` prop1/prop2 are not persisted. If I explicity call `prop1.save()` and `prop2.save()` they are stored in the _Isa95EquipmentSpecificationProperty_ collection. Both cases I find `"equipmentSpecificationProperties" : [ null, null ]`. I query mongodb using mongo shell and I expect to find at least some refs in equipmentSpecificationProperties

Comment: no, you shouldn't call `prop.save()`.
what do you mean by `find at least some refs in equipmentSpecificationProperties`? there should not be any refs at all, the props are to be saved directly as sub-docs

Comment: btw, specify the list type: `List<Isa95EquipmentSpecificationProperty> equipmentSpecificationProperties`

Comment: `List<Isa95EquipmentSpecificationProperty>` didn't solve the problem. I hope the document will be persisted as a single object, this is what I want

Comment: wwwwait, do you want to store props as subdocs within the same collection or as references pointing to another collection?

Comment: I've reboot the console and now it works! Thank you very match, the problem was the generic List

Comment: I want a single document and a single collection and it's what I get now, that's fine

Comment: I'll put is as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify the list type:

```
List<Isa95EquipmentSpecificationProperty> equipmentSpecificationProperties
```